# How scale the first character of string with css?

Tags: css

whether chinese or number ::first-letter only can select first letter not the first character.

```css
p::first-letter {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: brown;
}
```

```html
<p>Scientists exploring</p>
<p>3.5</p>
<p>我...是大傻帽</p>
```

Comment: Your examples all have the first character scaled up for me

Comment: But why are the dots selected too ?

Comment: @Axekan what I want is first character not first-letter

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The case is not with non-English characters only.

```css
p::first-letter {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: brown;
}
```

```html
<p>....Scientists exploring</p>
<p>3...5</p>
<p>我...是大傻帽</p>
```

Try placing the first character inside a `span` and it should work for the first character only.

```css
p::first-letter {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: brown;
}
```

```html
<p><span>我</span>...是大傻帽</p>
```